# General Mobile 21 Plus (Android 12) is automatically restricting some apps battery usage without my permission

Tags: applications, settings, battery-saver

I'm using [General Mobile 21 Plus](https://www.generalmobile.com/products/gm21plus) on Android 12. Sometimes I notice that some apps are not sending me notifications or the notifications are delayed.

So, I go to Settings -> Battery -> Battery Manager and I find Android had restricted the battery usage of some apps, so I go and uncheck the restriction on those apps and now the apps should use battery without restriction. The notifications are now coming as expected.

After a while, I find that Android had again re-restricted some apps without even asking me.

How can I prevent that annoying behavior and prevent Android from making these choices without my permission?

Comment: Battery saving is the part that is modified by most device manufacturer, so depending on the device manufacturer and model the battery saving feature may have only very little in common with what Google had developed for Android. Therefore asking such a question without naming manufacturer and device model will not get you any useful answer.

Comment: I updated the post adding my phone brand

Comment: [Don't kill my app!](https://dontkillmyapp.com/) is usually our go-to reference, though looks like this device is not yet explored.

Comment: Battery Manager automatically limits the battery for apps that you don't use often. Under the hood `RUN_ANY_IN_BACKGROUND` permission is denied for such apps. In AOSP there is an option to disable "Manage apps automatically". Your vendor might have removed / hidden this setting. [Here](https://mirfatif.github.io/IAnswers/stop_background_apps_in_android) is a detailed guide on how to stop / allow background execution of apps.